# Java get local internal Address

Tags: java, android, networking, ip

What I want is, how can I get internal IP address of the Hotspot when it is also connected with 4G LTE. The method that I have tried returns the external IP Address instead of the local one.

Example: 100.70.1.23 not 192.168.43.1

I want the the local address "192.168.43.1" ignoring the external address

```
public String getDeviceIpAddress() {

    String ip = "None";

    try {
        //Loop through all the network interface devices
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumeration = NetworkInterface
                .getNetworkInterfaces(); enumeration.hasMoreElements(); ) {
            NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumeration.nextElement();
            //Loop through all the ip addresses of the network interface devices
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumerationIpAddr = networkInterface.getInetAddresses(); enumerationIpAddr.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumerationIpAddr.nextElement();
                //Filter out loopback address and other irrelevant ip addresses
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && inetAddress.getAddress().length == 4) {
                    //device ip address
                    ip = inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ignored) {}

    return ip;
}
```

Comment: How much ip's do you get in that for loop? If there are more you get only the last one. Log them all to begin with. And break the loop at the first found.

Comment: Yes, it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Im not understand wrong you can get it like this :

```
public String getMyFacesIp() {
    String ip = "";
    try {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        while(interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface iface = interfaces.nextElement();
            if(iface.isLoopback() || !iface.isUp()) {
                continue;
            }

            Enumeration<InetAddress> addresses = iface.getInetAddresses();
            while(addresses.hasMoreElements()) {
                InetAddress addr = addresses.nextElement();
                ip = addr.getHostAddress();
                if(ip.startsWith("192")) {
                    return ip;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return ip;

}
```

Comment: I don't recommend the "192" because anyone can change that.